# Can I use a function for a default value in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I want to do something like this:

```
create table app_users
(
    app_user_id smallint(6) not null auto_increment primary key,
    api_key     char(36) not null default uuid()
);
```

However this results in a error, is there a way to call a function for a default value in mysql?

thanks.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

No, you can't.

However, you could easily create a trigger to do this, such as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_app_users
  BEFORE INSERT ON app_users 
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.api_key = uuid();
```

Comment: @See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280789/generate-guid-in-mysql-for-existing-data for populating UUIDs in existing rows.

Comment: This isn't quite the same as having a DEFAULT value. How would one change this answer to only set the key if the value was NULL?

Comment: I modified it with md5(uuid()) and worked fine. Was my aproach ok?

Comment: Sad that MySQL has been around for as long as it has but you can't implement a default UUID for a column without a trigger. The reason for this is embedded in the 1980's technology that apparently still exists in the MySQL base code (search for"we can't have nice things"): https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/04/08/understanding-the-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-mysql-table/

Comment: @RodolVelasco the uuid function is built to be highly collision resistant. Much more so than md5. As soon as you md5 the uuid you have a higher risk of id collision

Comment: `SET new.api_key = COALESCE(new.api_key, uuid())` to preserve existing values.

Comment: This is no true. It is possible to have a function set to a default value... at least nowadays. This answer has to be updated in order to keep its status of "Right Answer"

Answer (score 57):

As of [mysql v8.0.13](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) it is possible to use an expression as a default value for a field:

> The default value specified in a DEFAULT clause can be a literal constant or an expression. With one exception, enclose expression default values within parentheses to distinguish them from literal constant default values.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  uuid_field     VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT (uuid()),
  binary_uuid    BINARY(16)  DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()))
);
```

Comment: Note that as per the already linked docs in answer:
_... stored functions, and user-defined functions are not permitted_.  
I.e., the only functions that can be used as default expressions are built-in functions.

Comment: a minor detail: `varchar(32)` should be `varchar(36)`

Comment: @JaredBeck I think 32 is fine if you're not storing the dashes.

Comment: Note that if you are using MySQL Workbench, and decide to alter this table column at a later time with the given default previously set, Workbench removes the outer parenthesis creating an error.

Comment: For those using MariaDB a direct [UUID type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid-data-type/) without the `UUID_TO_BIN` (only the [UUID() function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid/) like [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/326456/158002).

Answer (score 24):

As already stated you can't.

If you want to simulate this behavior you can use a trigger in this way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_app_users
BEFORE INSERT ON app_users
FOR EACH ROW
  IF new.uuid IS NULL
  THEN
    SET new.uuid = uuid();
  END IF;
```

You still have to update previously existing rows, like this:

```
UPDATE app_users SET uuid = (SELECT uuid());
```

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately no, MySQL 5 requires constants for the default.  The issue was discussed in much more detail in the link below.  But the only answer is to allow null and add a table trigger.

MySQL only recently accepted UUID as part of their DB package, and it's not as feature rich as we'd like.

http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10349169

Comment: I should add that allowing NULL and relying on triggers may work, but most developers would consider it a very hack-y solution.  I wouldn't personally recommend it but to each their own.

Answer (score 7):

I believe [you can't](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression

Comment: Not true, you can use getdate()

Comment: @amrosama - No, you cannot. `getdate()` is not even a MySQL function. The link in the answer explains the only exception: *«you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column»*.

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is the only "function" that can be used as a default value. Everything else must be a constant (unfortunately).

Comment: Technically I'd say AUTO_INCREMENT can also be seen as a "function" to dynamically set a default value.

Answer (score 3):

Note that MySQL's `UUID()` returns `CHAR(36)`, and storing UUIDs as text (as shown in the other answers) is obviously inefficient.  Instead, the column should be `BINARY(16)`, and you can use `UUID_TO_BIN()` when inserting data and `BIN_TO_UUID()` when reading it back.

```
CREATE TABLE app_users
(
    app_user_id SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    api_key     BINARY(16)
);

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_app_users
BEFORE INSERT ON app_users
FOR EACH ROW
  IF new.api_key IS NULL
  THEN
    SET new.api_key = UUID_TO_BIN(UUID());
  END IF;
```

Note that since MySQL doesn't really know this is a UUID, it can be difficult to troubleshoot problems with it stored as binary.  This article explains how to create a generated column that will convert the UUID to text as needed without taking up any space or worrying about keeping separate binary and text versions in sync: https://mysqlserverteam.com/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/

Answer (score 3):

In MariaDB starting from version 10.2.1 you can. See [its documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#default).

```
CREATE TABLE test ( uuid BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT unhex(replace(uuid(),'-','')) );
INSERT INTO test () VALUES ();
SELECT * FROM test;
```

Answer (score 2):

Harrison Fisk's answer was great when it was written, but now it's outdated.

Nowadays you can use an expression as a `DEFAULT` value. This is supported since MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2. Note that, if you're going to use non-deterministic functions like `NOW()` or `USER()`, you should not use `binlog_format=statement`.

Comment: The reference manual for 5.7 states otherwise. -> "the default value specified in a DEFAULT clause must be a literal constant; it cannot be a function or an expression"
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html.

Comment: You are right, I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the above answers are for an older version, but I saw somewhere that you can do this using the unhex() function. I tried it and it works. (maria db version 10.2)

You can do

```
.... column_name binary(16) not null default unhex(replace(uuid(),'-',''))
```

and it works. To see the uuid just do hex(column_name).