# Simple.Data with Non Auto Increment Primary Key (uuid_short)

Tags: mysql, sql, simple.data

I am using [Simple.Data](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data#readme) as my Micro-ORM for my ASP.NET / MySQL website. I already know how to insert data when the primary key is auto incremental Int, but How can I insert data when I need to generate an idea using the [uuid_short()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short) function over a Bigint column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a trigger to set the column value, as in this answer: [Can I use a function for a default value in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql)

Or you can generate a value in your application code and insert it normally.

Comment: You mean run a select command with uui_short function against the DB and then make the insert?

Comment: Is there an option to do it without using triggers?

Comment: For example, make a select statement with uuid_short function, get the number and then insert. Will it work ok?

Comment: Do you specifically need UUID_SHORT? For a bigint column, DateTime.Now.Ticks would probably be unique.