# Perl DBIx::Class - Is it possible to provide a default value for inserting by using column attributes

Tags: perl, default-value, dbix-class

I have a (MySQL) table, *import*, defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `import` (
  `importId` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `stuff`    varchar(12) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`importId`),
  KEY `stuff` (`stuff`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I have used `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader->make_schema_at` to generate my DBIx::Class schema.

I want to be able to issue `$schema->resultset('Import')->create({});` (i.e., not providing a primary key) and have the importId field automatically populated with the result of a call to MySQL's `uuid()` function.  To attempt to do this, I added the following to the bottom of *Schema/Result/Import.pm*:

```
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:cKY/6hdjrNaMgdhm6SlzoQ

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper __PACKAGE__->columns_info();

__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
    '+importId' =>
    {
        default_value => \'uuid()',                              #'
    },
);

print Dumper __PACKAGE__->columns_info();
```

The data dumps show that the default_value attribute was added to importId, as expected:

```
$VAR1 = { 
      'importId' => { 
                      'data_type' => 'varchar',
                      'default_value' => \'uuid()',              #'
                      'is_nullable' => 0,
                      'size' => 36,
                      'accessor' => 'import_id'
                    },
      'stuff' => { 
                   'data_type' => 'varchar',
                   'is_nullable' => 1,
                   'size' => 12
                 }
};
```

But if I don't provide a value for importId in a `create()` call, DBIx::Class still issues `INSERT INTO import () VALUES ()`.

I did achieve what I wanted by modifying the `insert()` method by placing the following at the end of *Schema/Result/Import.pm*:

```
use Moo;

before 'insert' => sub
{   
    my $self = $_[0];
    my $column_data = $self->{_column_data};
    $column_data->{importId} = \'uuid()'                         #'
        unless exists $column_data->{importId} && defined $column_data->{importId};
};
```

I had thought I should be able to achieve this with the default_value column attribute.  Am I misunderstanding how this attribute works, or have I just implemented it incorrectly?

Comment: Primary keys are a database level construct, not an application level construct, so you might want ot consider performing this at the DB level a la this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read docs better.

Look into `L<DBIx::Class::ResultSource/add_columns>` for `default_value` and you will find that

> ```
> default_value
> ```
>
> Set this to the default value which will be inserted into a column by
>   the database. Can contain either a value or a function (use a
>   reference to a scalar e.g. \'now()' if you want a function). This is
>   currently only used to create tables from your schema, see "deploy" in
>   DBIx::Class::Schema.

So, if you don't use deployment via DBIC, you rather want to add `DEFAULT uuid()` into your SQL schema for corresponded column.

Comment: Thanks. I'd obviously glanced over the phrase "currently only used to create tables from your schema" without letting its meaning sink in.