# EF Code-First: Change datetime field to automated using MySQL

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I´m trying to update a MySql Database field to an automated datetime field using Migrations.

Here is the code:

```
    public partial class AutomatedDateField : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
    {
        this.AlterColumn("Orders", "Created", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"));
    }
```

Using SQL Server i would use `GETUTCDATE()` in defaultValueSql. What should i use in this case?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-date

Comment: I already tried utc_timespan() as well as utc_date() but i didn't succeed. When i run update-database in PMC i receive the error «You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UTC_DATE()' at line 1»

Comment: I guess the problem is in MySql version. The one i'm working on is 5.5.34 and it doesn't allow initialization values for datetime type. I had to handle that on SaveChanges method by capturing all added entity entries and setting Created to Datetime.UtcNow

Answer (score 0):

You can't use function as default value for column in MySQL.

Possible solution can be found here: [Can I use a function for a default value in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql)