# Convert query for trigger use

Tags: mysql, sql, date, triggers

This 2 query's works for me but now I need a converted version that works as trigger on every new insert!

Because I have this: #1442 - Can't update table 'reparatie' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

When I simply fill in the query codes!

```
INSERT INTO reparatie ( Weeknummer )
SELECT  WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())
```

AND

```
INSERT INTO reparatie ( Jaar )
SELECT  YEAR(NOW())
```

I hope that somebody can help me!

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql, please. Although not the same topic it should answer your question very well.

Comment: THNX @MyBrainHurts it solved my problem!!!