# MySQL set default id UUID

Tags: mysql, uuid

I'm trying to create tables in a database that has an `id` field that will populate the id with an UUID by default.

I tried something like:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
  id CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid()
);
```

I greatly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use a function for a default value in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql)

Answer (score 53):

### MySQL 5.7, 8.0.12 and older

MySQL as of 5.7 or 8.0.12 does not support using a function or expression as the default value of a column.

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; **it cannot be a function** or an expression.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html

The alternative would be to use a trigger to monitor the `BEFORE INSERT` of the desired table.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `foo_before_insert` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `foo` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF new.id IS NULL THEN
    SET new.id = uuid();
  END IF;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

This will change the default value of an `INSERT` statement to the `uuid()` value, unless it has been explicitly defined.

---

### MySQL 8.0.13 and newer

With the [release of MySQL 8.0.13](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html#mysqld-8-0-13-data-types) an expression can now be used as the default value, provided it is enclosed in parentheses.

Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=770004342be63adcca33553a000b334a)

> The default value specified in a `DEFAULT` clause can be a literal
> constant or an expression. With one exception, enclose expression
> default values within parentheses to distinguish them from literal
> constant default values.
> The exception is that, for `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns, you can specify the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` [constant] as the default, without enclosing parentheses.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE foo (b BINARY(16)  DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID())));
> ```
>
> When inserting a new row, the default value for a column with an expression default can be inserted either by omitting the column name or by specifying the column as `DEFAULT` (just as for columns with literal defaults):
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO foo () VALUES();
> INSERT INTO foo () VALUES(DEFAULT);
> ```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'm a little confused why the uuid doesn't work, but the timestamp now() does.

Comment: The function `NOW()` isn't used, but the constant `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  is.

Comment: Meaning after executing `DEFAULT NOW()` it will be converted to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` when using `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo`.

Comment: A short explanation of why they decided to not support using a function as a default would be nice.

Comment: I suggest having the following condition to ensure we can't insert an empty string: `IF new.id IS NULL OR new.id = '' THEN ...`

Comment: The conditional as provided is intended to function how MySQL typically handles a `DEFAULT` column value to allow `UUID` as the `PRIMARY KEY` replacement. Which would allow `''` but error if it exists or when strict mode is enabled. It would be up to the developer to determine their desired end-results such as `IF CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(NEW.id)) = 0 THEN ...` as another alternative to prevent `NULL` or empty strings from being inserted, or by even ensuring the UUID 128-bit length is met.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I can insert with UUID without adding in my query.

Comment: How would you do for MAriaDB 10+ ?

Comment: @S.W.G. same way as described just not using a `BINARY(16)` datatype with `UUID_TO_BIN`, since MariaDB doesn't support it - so you'd need to declare your own function to convert it with something like `(UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),'-','')))`,  https://dbfiddle.uk/QAzGfHsI  otherwise use `VARCHAR(36)` with `UUID()`. https://dbfiddle.uk/KjgsN1lP - Should probably submit a question for MariaDB rather than asking in a comment to a MySQL specific question.

Answer (score 13):

for Mysql version 8 and above the answer is found in; [Can I use a function for a default value in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql)

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (   'uuid_field' VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT (uuid());
```

Comment: The solution described doesn't work with MySQL 8.0.17 and the default value generated is "uuid()" instead of a uuid

Answer (score 1):

If you use `binary(16)` as the type, you can set the default as follows:

```
unhex(replace(uuid(),'-',''))
```

Comment: This is the only method I was able to get any traction with in MariaDB 10.6.12, except I had to enclose it in parentheses: `(unhex(replace(uuid(),'-','')))`