# mysql set current user as default value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a table which will be filled with records uploaded from other devices and I want to make a column which value is the user, who uploaded it.

I know I can get the actual user with  **`select CURRENT_USER();`** , but can not make that  **`user varchar(20)`** by selecting it like:
**`user_id varchar(20) default select CURRENT_USER() LIMIT 1`**

Comment: I think you have to use a trigger for this, because `current_user()` is a volatile function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql

Comment: That trigger in Alex's link is exactly what you need. Replace with something like  `NEW.userwhouploadedit = CURRENT_USER()`