# Insert row into MySQL table with default column value derived from other value

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Given the following example table, I would like the default value of `str_field_hash` to contain the SHA1 hash of the value of `str_field`.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    str_field VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
    str_field_hash CHAR(40) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT str_field_hash_unique UNIQUE (str_field_hash)
);
```

`str_field` is too large for a unique key constraint.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql) contains answers indicating the newer versions of MySQL/MariaDB support using functions in default column values, though I've been unable to find information on whether I can derive a default value for a column from the value provided for another column.

I know I can use a trigger for this, but I'd love to keep it all confined to the table schema itself if possible.

Developing using MySQL v8.0.11.

Comment: Specify DBMS and its version in interest precisely.

Comment: Updated the question. Version is `MySQL v8.0.11`.

Comment: If so read [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Data Types  /  Data Type Default Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html). No functions except current_timestamp.

Comment: That is clearly incorrect, given that the samples themselves demonstrate the use of `UUID_TO_BIN(UUID())`.

Comment: Please try to find the text part relative to YOUR server version...