# Create table and set default value to NOW() + 24 hours

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to create a table and set the default value to now() + 24 hours. I'm getting syntax errors when trying to do this.

This doesn't work

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
    `my_table_id` CHAR(36) BINARY NOT NULL , 
    `expiration_time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (NOW() + INTERVAL 24 HOUR),
    PRIMARY KEY (`my_table_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Although this does work `SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 24 HOUR;` so i'm not sure why it doesn't work when trying to create a table.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52769071/2055998) is helpful.

Comment: Do you mean "24 hours from now" or "the same time tomrrow"? Daylight savings time means they can be different!

Comment: 24 hours from now, disregarding daylight savings.

Comment: @PM77-1 this comment from that answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql/52769071#comment123614916_69688616. I guess unsupported in mysql 5.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a function for a default value in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Expressions for defaults are not supported in MySQL 5.7.

You can implement a "default" expression in a trigger such as the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_awesome_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.expiration_time = COALESCE(NEW.expiration_time, NOW() + INTERVAL 24 HOUR));
```